# How to make a function of an object that doesn't stop even closing it's form in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

My problem is that after closing the frame for admin that will set the available products the selected products gets unselected

[image: image1]

The checkbox here must get activated by the admin from the other form

[image: image2]

Here's my code:

```
private void chk1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Cashier x = new Cashier();

    if (chk1.isSelected() == true)
    {
        x.chkpr1.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        x.chkpr1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` goes out of scope after your method. Which is functionally identical to `x.chkpr1.setEnabled(chk1.isSelected());`

Comment: My checkbox from the 2nd frame still doesn't get enabled.

Comment: should i put the function in a button?